# Structure pointer implementation method

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
struct _Structure{
   int member;
};
```

**Structure Pointer**

**Pointer to Structure**

Is there any difference between above 2 phrases

In my opinion, both phrases represents different pointer instantiation

Structure Pointer

```
typedef struct _Structure *SP;

SP sp;
```

Pointer to Structure

```
typedef struct _Structure PS;

PS *ps;
```

While concerning data member access of _Structure both having same code snip

```
sp->member;
    AND
ps->member
```

IF BOTH PHRASES ARE SAME, OK NOPS!!!

In addition with this, why we need

```
typedef struct _Structure *SP;

SP *sp;

//note: here 'sp' is like double pointer
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: what are you actually asking about, though?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the `typedefs`, both `sp` and `ps` are of type `struct _Structure *`. In that respect, there is absolutely no difference between them.

Obviously, the `typedefs` themselves (`SP` and `PS`) have different semantics, since one is a pointer, and the other isn't.

In the last example, `sp` is not *like* a double, it *is* a double pointer. Double pointers are useful in some contexts, but are used less frequently than single pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two expressions *Structure pointer* and *Pointer to structure*.

And there is no difference between `sp` and `ps` variables. Both are pointers to a structure. Using the `*` in the `typedef` or in the variable declaration makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

No difference and more over in

```
    typedef struct _Structure *SP;

SP *sp;

//note: here 'sp' is like double pointer
```

You don't need this. If you do this, you will just have a pointer to a pointer as you said.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both phrases are equivalent. Both require to implement struct. It's only a programming preference to `typedef` a pointer and declare it or declare a pointer to struct.